# Finding empty area in an Image to fill another image

Tags: android, image, canvas

I want to find empty area in an image (its x-y co-ordinates); from that I need to fill another image in that empty area.

[image: Empty area to be found for this image]

Answer (score 1):

By empty area do you mean a white rect?

The way I'd go about this is I'd run pixel per pixel (x axis/y axis) searching for a totally white pixel, once I have found this pixel I'd run a method which, starting from that pixel, verifies the pixels along a straight line on the X axis and another for the Y axis in the amount of the width and height of the image I want to insert there. In case it's all white on those 2 lines then I'd run it again on a diagonal line which length would be `math.sqrt(width*width + height*height)`, if it's all white, I could fill the image there, if it's not, keep the search going starting from the end of that diagonal line.

Though instead of searching for white pixels I'd rather search for fully transparent pixels (0 alpha). I think that would work for your image but it would fail in case you happen to have another image with 3 lines that have those exact lengths united by their tail, and white. Just don't... do that.

Instead of only checking those lines you could actually verify all of the pixels in that rect, but that would probably be slow and wouldn't work for your image since you happen to have that elevation on the bottom of the empty area.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find WHITE point in image then try below .
I hope it will help you, but it return all WHITE point in the image not only empty area.

```
            Bitmap mBitmap = YOUR BITMAP;

            ArrayList<Point> whitePoint = new ArrayList<Point>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mBitmap.getWidth(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mBitmap.getHeight(); j++) {
                    if(mBitmap.getPixel(i, j) == Color.WHITE)
                    {
                        whitePoint.add(new Point(i, j));
                    }
                }
            }
```

I suggest that use TRANSPARENT color in empty area and check TRANSPARENT instead of WHITE color

Comment: Okay thanks . But how can i add transparent color to empty area without knowing x,y co-ordinates?

Comment: make image from designer or change bitmap like as mBitmap.setPixel(x, y, transparentcolor)

Comment: Images are dynamic from Service call

Comment: hmmm :).. change bitmap like as mBitmap.setPixel(x, y, transparentcolor)

Comment: forgot about transparent color, carry on yr work.. you will got all point which are in white area using my code